# Set MySQL connection flags from command line client

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to set MySQL client flags when using the command line client?

I would like to set the `CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` client flag, but the manpages of the mysql client do not mention the setting of client flags. This is only documented in the documentation of the `mysql_real_connect()` function.

Is using client flags in the command line client at all possible? If so, how?

The problem at hand is this. I am using the command line mysql client. After an update statement, I would like to be able to issue a SELECT ROW_COUNT() command, and have it return the number of rows matched, not the number of rows changed. When accessing the database via a library where you can call the mysql_real_connect() function, this can be achieved by setting the CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS client flag. I would like to achive the same behaviour but with the command line client instead.

I know I could screen scrape the output of the sql update statement, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: @RickJames This is an update statement, so I'm not getting a result set back.

Comment: My bad--I misread.

Comment: I do not see a function to achieve your goal -- return count of rows _looked at_ by an `UPDATE`.  What would you then do the the number?

Comment: It determines the flow of the rest of the script. This is becoming a bit academic. There are several other solutions for the problem I had. I just thought it strange that you can control a MySQL connection with several client flags if setup via a library and that this functionality is not available when using the command line client. I was wondering if maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

`CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS` isn't a flag for the command line because the command line already tells you how many rows it matched/updated. That option only works for the `mysql_real_connect()` function because it tells the function to return the number of rows as part of the return value (otherwise that data would be lost.)

Comment: How about client flags in general?

Comment: Here's a list of command line options - https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/The_mysql_Command-Line_Tool

Comment: Thanks Bob, but that doesn't answer my question. I know my way around manpages and the mysql client command line options. I've expanded the question a bit.

Comment: Everything available in the man pages is everything available to the command line client. Why don't you use a COUNT(*) in your SELECT statement if you want to also know the number of rows?